# Is there a way to avoid repetition in each of these location?

Tags: nginx, repeat

I have this nginx virtual site:

```
server {
    server_name custom_name;

    listen 80 http2;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass          "http://0.0.0.0:4000";
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass          "http://0.0.0.0:4000";

        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "";
        proxy_buffering     off;
    }

    # and other locations here...
}
```

As you can see I have these lines repeated:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
proxy_pass          "http://0.0.0.0:4000";
```

Is there a way to avoid this repetition?